# Docker Host iptables

Tags: iptables, docker

Using our stock iptables based on a default DROP policy, Dockerfiles based on Ubuntu or Debian are unable to resolve hosts on apt-get commands, making it impossible to build the files.
If I change the default policy to ACCEPT it works as expected, so can confirm iptables is the problem.
It's there a set of rules that need to be enabled for docker build to work? I've already allowed DNS port 53 INPUT/OUTPUT/FORWARD along with ports 80 and 443

Comment: Put logging entries in your firewall and see what turns up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by iptables dropping a FORWARD from docker0 to eth0
See this [blog post](https://blog.andyet.com/2014/09/11/docker-host-iptables-forwarding) for more information